# Cannot convert value of type [AnyObject] to expected argument type [SKAction]

Tags: xcode, swift, skaction

About the 2nd line:

```
var actionArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
human1.runAction(SKAction.repeatAction(SKAction.sequence(actionArray as [AnyObject]), count: -1))
```

Was working fine on the previous xCode, got error when updated to he new xCode.
How do I get rid of the error?

Error: Cannot convert value of type [AnyObject] to expected argument type [SKAction]

//////EDIT:

```
    var actionArray = [SKAction]()
    actionArray.addObject(SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(posAutoY1, -3*frame.size.height/20), duration: NSTimeInterval(duration1)))
    actionArray.addObject(SKAction.removeFromParent())
    auto1.runAction(SKAction.sequence(actionArray as [SKAction]))
```

If use these lines of code, the first error gets solved but I get another error: value of type [SKAction] has no member addObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Append() method.

```
anArray.append("This String")
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear about what the problem is: the expected argument to `SKAction.sequence(_)` is an array of `SKAction`s, not an array of `AnyObject`s. You are explicitly casting `actionArray` to `[AnyObject]` for some reason; just cast to `[SKAction]` instead:

```
human1.runAction(SKAction.repeatAction(SKAction.sequence(actionArray as! [SKAction]), count: -1))
```

However, it'd be even better to declare your `actionArray` as `[SKAction]` to begin with! `NSMutableArray` is old school.

```
var actionArray = [SKAction]()
actionArray.append(SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(posAutoY1, -3*frame.size.height/20), duration: NSTimeInterval(duration1)))
actionArray.append(SKAction.removeFromParent())
auto1.runAction(SKAction.sequence(actionArray))
```

Comment: Your first solution worked, but when I declare the mutablearray as SKAction, I get another error, see edit.

Comment: Yes, that error is pretty clear, too: Swift's `Array` doesn't have an `addObject(_)` method. But if you check the documentation in Xcode, you'll see it has an `append(_)` method which does what you want.